# Trivia... sudoku

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, no-computers, grid-deduction, sudoku

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #49: Pub Quiz Camouflage](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7159/)</sup>

---

Please **do not search the answers online** (hence the [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) tag), otherwise it would be too simple to solve this puzzle. I tried to recreate the team-play spirit of the pub quiz challenges by designing this puzzle such that it is possible for different people to answer different questions. So I would rather prefer a community-wiki answers with a lot of contributors than an answer with the solution found online.

[image: grid]

You need to fill the grid by answering the questions below and by applying the normal sudoku rules.

Each table R1-R9 corresponds to a row of the sudoku. For each table, match each element from the first column (C1-C9) to the correct number in the second column or in the images (1-9). Then write that number in the corresponding cell. For example, if you think that Gregor Mendel was born in 1933, write 5 in R1C3.

***R1 - match each scientist to their birth year***

| R1 |  |
| --- | --- |
| C1 Carlo Rubbia | 1. 1809 |
| C2 Pythagoras | 2. 1822 |
| C3 Gregor Mendel | 3. 1934 |
| C4 Edsger Wybe Dijkstra | 4. 1885 |
| C5 Stanley Milgram | 5. 1933 |
| C6 Leonardo Da Vinci | 6. circa 570 BC |
| C7 Charles Darwin | 7. 1452 |
| C8 Otto Brunfels | 8. 1930 |
| C9 Niels Bohr | 9. 1488 |

***R2 - match each food/recipe to its main ingredient***

| R2 |  |
| --- | --- |
| C1 Amasi | 1. semolina |
| C2 Galaktoboureko | 2. soybeans |
| C3 Pao cai | 3. young-coconut |
| C4 Miso | 4. pasta |
| C5 Gravlax | 5. milk |
| C6 Carbonara | 6. bread |
| C7 Knödel | 7. cabbage |
| C8 Snert | 8. pea |
| C9 Buko pie | 9. salmon |

***R3 - match each fruit to its image***

| R3 |  |
| --- | --- |
| C1 Loquat | 1. [image: im1] |
| C2 Babaco | 2. [image: im2] |
| C3 Elderberry | 3. [image: im3] |
| C4 Crane Melon | 4. [image: im4] |
| C5 Kabosu | 5. [image: im5] |
| C6 Soncoya | 6. [image: im6] |
| C7 Orange | 7. [image: im7] |
| C8 Jackfruit | 8. [image: im8] |
| C9 Durian | 9. [image: im9] |

***R4 - match each place or monument to its position in the map of Madrid below***

| R4 |
| --- |
| C1 Mercado de San Miguel |
| C2 Puerta del sol |
| C3 Gran via |
| C4 Monumento a Álvaro de Bazán |
| C5 Monasterio de las Descalzas |
| C6 Plaza mayor |
| C7 Teatro Albéniz |
| C8 Thyssen-Bornemisza National Museum |
| C9 Palacio real |

[image: madrid map]

***R5 - match each number to its property***

| R5 |  |
| --- | --- |
| C1 247 | 1. pentagonal number |
| C2 608 | 2. happy number |
| C3 642 | 3. factorial number |
| C4 1089 | 4. polydivisible number |
| C5 144 | 5. sphenic number |
| C6 6 | 6. fibonacci number |
| C7 5040 | 7. nonagonal number |
| C8 1020 | 8. super prime number |
| C9 1063 | 9. perfect number |

***R6 - match each band to its singer***

| R6 |  |
| --- | --- |
| C1 Chicago | 1. Paul McCartney |
| C2 Linkin Park | 2. Robert Plant |
| C3 Daft Punk | 3. Chester Bennington |
| C4 The Doors | 4. Ray Manzarek |
| C5 Led Zeppelin | 5. Annette Zilinskas |
| C6 The Beatles | 6. Ian Paice |
| C7 Cranberries | 7. Dolores O'Riordan |
| C8 The Bangles | 8. Robert Lamm |
| C9 Deep Purple | 9. Thomas Bangalter |

***R7 - match each muscle to its position in the human body in the image below***

| R7 |
| --- |
| C1 Pectineus |
| C2 Iliopsoas |
| C3 Occipitofrontalis |
| C4 Pectoralis major |
| C5 Sorratus anterior |
| C6 Deltoid |
| C7 Fibularis Longus |
| C8 Sternocleidomastoid |
| C9 Vastus medialis |

[image: muscles]

***R8 - match each job to its explanation***

| R8 |  |
| --- | --- |
| C1 Rigger | 1. studies the amphibians |
| C2 Minstrel | 2. prompts dance figures |
| C3 CGO | 3. studies the life prior to the Holocene |
| C4 Herpetologist | 4. heads the game development |
| C5 Tweener | 5. sing songs and play musical instruments |
| C6 Caller | 6. moves large, heavy objects |
| C7 Endocrinologist | 7. Makes drawings between the key poses |
| C8 Paleontologist | 8. Cures hormones diseases |
| C9 Call Boy | 9. alerts actors and actresses of their entrances |

***R9 - match each Disney characters to its movie***

| R9 |  |
| --- | --- |
| C1 Pinocchio | 1. Chick |
| C2 Peter Pan | 2. Candlewick |
| C3 Sleeping Beauty | 3. Herald |
| C4 The Sword in the Stone | 4. Ursula |
| C5 The Aristocats | 5. Friar Tuck |
| C6 Robin Hood | 6. Phoebus |
| C7 The Little Mermaid | 7. Michael Darling |
| C8 The Hunchback of Notre Dame | 8. Roquefort |
| C9 Cars | 9. Sir Bart |

<sub>Acknowledgment: I took all the images from Wikipedia and the map from Open Street Map (license CC-BY)</sub>

Comment: Are partial answers allowed?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget sure!

Comment: I see you have referenced Indonesia in here with Durian. Nice! I'm from Indonesia, if you haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: @Anonymus25-ReinstateMonica nice to hear that, I see you can solve part of the puzzle!

Comment: Can my partial answer not include the grid? I'm from mobile, so I can't make a grid

Comment: @Anonymus25-ReinstateMonica It would be better if you include a grid. You can use a spreadsheet like libreoffice or google sheet to meke the grid. Read more here: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7007/how-do-you-draw-the-grid-puzzles-and-partial-solutions

Comment: Well, I'm trying, but it's practically impossible cuz spreadsheets is too complicated. Since it's a community wiki, can you add it for me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119775/discussion-between-melfnt-and-anonymus-25-reinstate-monica).

Comment: Is it allowed to include an answer with the solution to a sudoku?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget sure, why not? Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved sudoku (nothing fancy, just plain logical deduction):

> $$
> \begin{array}{c|ccc|ccc|ccc|}
>    & C1 & C2 & C3 \ & C4 & C5 & C6 \ & C7 & C8 & C9 \\ \hline
> R1 & 3  & 6  &  2 \ & 8  & 5  & 7  \ & 1  & 9  &  4 \\ 
> R2 & 5  & 1  &  7 \ & 2  & 9  & 4  \ & 6  & 8  &  3 \\ 
> R3 & 4  & 9  &  8 \ & 3  & 1  & 6  \ & 2  & 7  &  5 \\ \hline
> %--------------------------------------------------------
> R4 & 7  &  4 &  6 \ & 5  & 3  & 8  \ & 9  & 1  &  2 \\ 
> R5 & 1  &  2 &  5 \ & 7  & 6  & 9  \ & 3  & 4  &  8 \\ 
> R6 & 8  &  3 &  9 \ & 4  & 2  & 1  \ & 7  & 5  &  6 \\ \hline
> %--------------------------------------------------------
> R7 & 9  & 8  & 1  \ & 6  & 4  & 3  \ & 5  & 2  &  7 \\ 
> R8 & 6  & 5  & 4  \ & 1  & 7  & 2  \ & 8  & 3  &  9 \\ 
> R9 & 2  & 7  & 3  \ & 9  & 8  & 5  \ & 4  & 6  &  1 \\ \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

---

Here is the partially completed sudoku grid using the trivia only. (Please check and update the ones you know!):

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc|ccc|ccc|}
   & C1 & C2 & C3 \ & C4 & C5 & C6 \ & C7 & C8 & C9 \\ \hline
R1 &    & 6  & 2  \ &    &    & 7  \ & 1  &    &    \\ 
R2 &    &    &  7 \ & 2  & 9  & 4  \ &    &    &    \\ 
R3 & 4  &    &  8 \ & 3  &    & 6  \ & 2  & 7  &  5 \\ \hline
%--------------------------------------------------------
R4 & 7  &  4 &  6 \ &    &    & 8  \ &    &    &    \\ 
R5 & 1  &  2 &    \ &    & 6  & 9  \ & 3  & 4  &  8 \\ 
R6 & 8  &  3 &  9 \ & 4  & 2  & 1  \ & 7  & 5  &  6 \\ \hline
%--------------------------------------------------------
R7 & 9  & 8  & 1  \ & 6  & 4  & 3  \ & 5  & 2  &  7 \\ 
R8 & 6  & 5  & 4  \ & 1  & 7  & 2  \ & 8  & 3  &  9 \\ 
R9 & 2  & 7  & 3  \ & 9  & 8  & 5  \ & 4  & 6  &  1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

**R1**: Scientist → Birth year

- C1 → ??
- C2 → 6, Pythagoras = circa 570 BC (@newQOpenGLWidget)
- C3 → 2, Gregor Mendel = 1822 (@Stiv)
- C4 → ??
- C5 → ??
- C6 → 7, Leonardo Da Vinci = 1452 (@Stiv)
- C7 → 1, Charles Darwin = 1809 (@Stiv)
- C8 → ??
- C9 → ??

**R2**: Food → main ingredient

- C1 → ??
- C2 → ??
- C3 → 7, Pao cai = cabbage (@WhatsUp)
- C4 → 2, Miso = soybeans (@WhatsUp)
- C5 → 9, Gravlax = salmon (@Stiv)
- C6 → 4, Carbonara = pasta (@justhalf)
- C7 → ??
- C8 → ??
- C9 → ??

**R3**: Fruit names → Fruit images

- C1 → 4 = Loquat (@JProblems)
- C2 → ??
- C3 → 8 = Elderberry (@justhalf)
- C4 → 3 = Crane melon (@JeremyDover)
- C5 → ??
- C6 → 6 = soncoya (@Stiv)
- C7 → 2 = orange (@newQOpenGLWidget)
- C8 → 7 = jackfruit (@justhalf)
- C9 → 5 = durian (@Stiv)

**R4**: Madrid monument → Map

- C1 → 7 = Mercado de San Miguel (@WhatsUp)
- C2 → 4 = Monumento a Álvaro de Bazán (@WhatsUp)
- C3 → 6 = Plaza mayor (@WhatsUp)
- C4 → ??
- C5 → ??
- C6 → 8 = Thyssen-Bornemisza National Museum (@WhatsUp)
- C7 → ??
- C8 → ??
- C9 → ??

**R5**: Number → Property

- C1 → 1, 247 = 12th pentagonal number (@JeremyDover)
- C2 → 2, 608 = happy number (@Danis)
- C3 → ??
- C4 → ??
- C5 → 6, 144 = fibonacci number (@newQOpenGLWidget)
- C6 → 9, 6 = perfect number (@newQOpenGLWidget)
- C7 → 3, 5040 = factorial number (@newQOpenGLWidget)
- C8 → 4, 1020 = polydivisible number (@newQOpenGLWidget)
- C9 → 8, 1063 = super prime number (@JProblems)

**R6**: Band → Singer

- C1 → 8, Chicago = Robert Lamm (@Stiv)
- C2 → 3, Linkin Park = Chester Bennington (@JeremyDover)
- C3 → 9, Daft Punk = Thomas Bangalter (@Stiv)
- C4 → 4, The Doors = Ray Manzarek (@JeremyDover)
- C5 → 2, Led Zeppelin = Robert Plant (@JeremyDover)
- C6 → 1, The Beatles = Paul McCartney (@JeremyDover)
- C7 → 7, Cranberries = Dolores O'Riordan (@JeremyDover)
- C8 → 5, The Bangles = Annette Zilinskas (@JeremyDover)
- C9 → 6, Deep Purple = Ian Paize (@JeremyDover)

**R7**: Muscle name → Picture

- C1 → 9 = Pectineus (@JeremyDover)
- C2 → 8 = Iliopsoas (@JeremyDover)
- C3 → 1 = Occipitofrontalis (@Stiv)
- C4 → 6 = Pectoralis major (@Stiv)
- C5 → 4 = S**e**rratus (sic) anterior (@Stiv)
- C6 → 3 = Deltoid (@Stiv)
- C7 → 5 = Fibularis Longus (@Stiv)
- C8 → 2 = Sternocleidomastoid (@Stiv)
- C9 → 7 = Vastus medialis (@Stiv)

**R8**: Job → Explanation

- C1 → 6, Rigger = moves large, heavy objects (@Stiv)
- C2 → 5, Minstrel = sings songs and plays musical instruments (@Stiv)
- C3 → 4, CGO = heads the game development (@Stiv)
- C4 → 1, Herpetologist = studies the amphibians (@JeremyDover)
- C5 → 7, Tweener = Makes drawings between the key poses (@JeremyDover)
- C6 → 2, Caller = prompts dance figures (in a square dance) (@JeremyDover)
- C7 → 8, Endocrinologist = cures hormone diseases (@Stiv)
- C8 → 3, Paleontologist = studies the life before the Holocene (@newQOpenGLWidget)
- C9 → 9, Call boy = alerts actors and actresses of their entrances (@JeremyDover)

**R9**: Disney movie → character

- C1 → 2, Pinocchio = Candlewick (@Stiv)
- C2 → 7, Peter Pan = Michael Darling (@newQOpenGLWidget)
- C3 → 3, Sleeping Beauty = Herald (@Stiv, as last one left!)
- C4 → 9, The Sword in the Stone = Sir Bart (@Stiv)
- C5 → 8, The Aristocats = Roquefort (@Stiv)
- C6 → 5, Robin Hood = Friar Tuck (@Stiv)
- C7 → 4, The Little Mermaid = Ursula (@newQOpenGLWidget)
- C8 → 6, The Hunchback of Notre Dame = Phoebus (@Stiv)
- C9 → 1, Cars = Chick (@Anonymus25-ReinstateMonica)
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmIbU.png

Comment: I think for R9, C9 is 1, and C8 is 5

Comment: For R4: C1 = 7, C2 = 4, C6 = 8. I happen to know these, because I once booked a hotel near the Mercado! Unfortunately I forgot the other names... But C3 = 6 as it's shown on the map...

Comment: Also for R2: C3 = 7, C4 = 2.

Comment: Also, R3: C9=6, only true Indonesians and Malaysians know that

Comment: @Anonymus, durians are also popular in Phillipines and Thailand :)

Comment: There is a lot of deduction that can be done by Sudoku logic at this point (filling out R5 and the left-side middle-row box, for example). I'm not sure how you would like that displayed. Just putting it out there.

Comment: Yea, but some of the entries are wrong (e.g., R6 C8-C9), so I'm not sure how to proceed. Previously I included another grid for the deduction. But since there are errors I thought it would be better for the community to double check the existing answers first before deducing.

Comment: `R5: C9 - 1063`

Comment: Okay, I've gone through and reformatted for aesthetics, removing extraneous words ('found by' just made mess!) and adding in the ones I know for sure. I think this corrects all of the inconsistencies at the same time.

Comment: @bobble True, but I think the OP's intent on this is primarily to be a quiz rather than a sudoku (it's just a quiz that happens to yield a sudoku grid), so maybe we should give it a week or so for people to answer as many of the trivia questions as they know without using the grid and then only solve by logic once no more are found? How does that sound? :)

Comment: @Stiv the grid is getting big, it should be able to be solved by logic now

Comment: @Anonymus25-ReinstateMonica Indeed, it doubtless *can* be solved be logic now - but the question is whether that's what melfnt (as the OP) *wants* us to do. The tone of the question suggests that they want to see as much of it as possible answered by trivia alone first ("*I tried to recreate the team-play spirit of the pub quiz challenges*", etc.) - so I would leave the answer open a while longer to allow more people to try and chip in if they know something :)

Comment: @Stiv (and others) yes, you are allowed to use sudoku deduction at any time. I think the teamwork is necessary to place enough numbers in the grid, but then you can treat it just like a normal sudoku (:

Comment: Thanks @melfnt - noted. newQOpenGLWidget: Care to finish off what you began? :)

Comment: @Stiv I just noticed that the sudoku grid is not valid. In the leftmost column, there are two numbers that are the same.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget That might mean that R7 C1 and C2 need to be swapped. In fact, at this stage I've now googled those two (as I always get them mixed up - I work with medical imaging: CT scans and the like) and I'm pretty sure they're the wrong way round - swap those, then you're probably good to go!

Comment: for fruit, R3C1 = 4. We used to have a loquat tree in the courtyard of our apartment in LA.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure R5C9 = 8, 1063 is super prime.

Comment: Thanks Stiv for the formatting update! Looks nicer now. And I can't believe I mixed up Durian vs Soncoya, lol. The durian picture is quite low res that I didn't see it as durian, haha.

As for the completed grid based on sudoku logic, perhaps create another grid for that, until we fill up everything in the trivia grid.

Comment: Oh, ok, just found out that soncoya is called (translated) durian sugar apple in Indonesian, because it is a sugar apple that looks like durian, haha.

Comment: Lol, it's probably as good as mangosteen

Comment: @Anonymus25-ReinstateMonica You're becoming annoying

Comment: "Gala" means "milk" in Greek, so I think in R2, C2 "galatoboureko" is 5, milk. I believe it's a pastry.

Comment: @Stiv Sudoku done!